# random images without repeat on click

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, image, random

Currently I'm working on this website and I made a random image pop up on click, but my client feels like sometimes one image keep repeating too many times so they asked me to make the it random but without repetition.

This is the website link: http://fullbleed.life/about/ (the PAST WORK section is where it should work)

Thank you!

```js
imageString = [
  'http://fullbleed.life/wp-content/uploads/1.png',
  'http://fullbleed.life/wp-content/uploads/2.png',
  'http://fullbleed.life/wp-content/uploads/3.png',
  'http://fullbleed.life/wp-content/uploads/4.png',
  'http://fullbleed.life/wp-content/uploads/5.png',
  'http://fullbleed.life/wp-content/uploads/6.png',
  'http://fullbleed.life/wp-content/uploads/7.png',
  'http://fullbleed.life/wp-content/uploads/8.png',
  'http://fullbleed.life/wp-content/uploads/9.png',
  'http://fullbleed.life/wp-content/uploads/10.png',
]

name = [
  'Nordstrom',
  'Pylon',
  'ASP & Hand',
  'faris',
  'ARA',
  'traceme',
  'Microsoft',
  'Kozha Numbers',
  'Van Der Pop',
  'YFF',
]

function getRandom() {
  var min = 0
  var max = 10
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max)
}

$('.past-work').bind('click', function(event) {

  var randNum = getRandom()
  var aProduct = document.getElementById('rand-images')
  var image = document.createElement('img')
  image.src = imageString[randNum]
  image.style.display = 'block'
  image.style.position = 'absolute'
  image.style.left = event.clientX - 280 + 'px'
  image.style.top = event.clientY - 280 + 'px'
  aProduct.appendChild(image)

  $(image).draggable()
      event.preventDefault()
})
```

```html
<body><div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-12 past-work">
  <h1>PAST WORK</h1>
  <h4>(CLICK ANYWHERE, CLICK ANYWHERE AGAIN)</a></h4>
  <div class="picture">
  <div id="rand-images">
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 
 
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: What happened when you only have a image string in `imageString` and you don't want to display a image twice times?

Comment: Hmm I don't really understand it ...

Comment: Do you want to display a different image every time the user _hover's_ over an element with the `past-work` class? Please add more information for the specific problem you are trying to solve :)

Comment: hi @luchosrock , I'm trying to make the past work section work like how it is right now (which is a random image pop up every time I click on the div) , but the problem is that right the image got repeated in a row, and I don't want it to be like that

Answer (score 0):

You could remove image in array after appear it.

```js
imageString = [
  'http://fullbleed.life/wp-content/uploads/1.png',
  'http://fullbleed.life/wp-content/uploads/2.png',
  'http://fullbleed.life/wp-content/uploads/3.png',
  'http://fullbleed.life/wp-content/uploads/4.png',
  'http://fullbleed.life/wp-content/uploads/5.png',
  'http://fullbleed.life/wp-content/uploads/6.png',
  'http://fullbleed.life/wp-content/uploads/7.png',
  'http://fullbleed.life/wp-content/uploads/8.png',
  'http://fullbleed.life/wp-content/uploads/9.png',
  'http://fullbleed.life/wp-content/uploads/10.png',
]

name = [
  'Nordstrom',
  'Pylon',
  'ASP & Hand',
  'faris',
  'ARA',
  'traceme',
  'Microsoft',
  'Kozha Numbers',
  'Van Der Pop',
  'YFF',
]

var aProduct = document.getElementById('rand-images');
var image = document.createElement('img');
var min = 0;
var max = 10;
function getRandom() {
  
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max)
}

$('.past-work').bind('click', function(event) {
if(max >=min){
  var randNum = getRandom();  
  image.src = imageString[randNum];
  imageString.splice(randNum, 1) ;
  max--; 
  image.style.display = 'block';
  image.style.position = 'absolute';
  image.style.left = event.clientX - 280 + 'px';
  image.style.top = event.clientY - 280 + 'px';
  aProduct.appendChild(image);
}

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-12 past-work">
  <h1>PAST WORK</h1>
  <h4>(CLICK ANYWHERE, CLICK ANYWHERE AGAIN)</a></h4>
  <div class="picture">
  <div id="rand-images">
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 
 
</div>
```

Comment: it doesn't work :(( maybe I put it wrong? Where should I put the code in? cảm ơn bạn nhiều nha!

Comment: it still doesn't work... The images wouldn't show up now